# How i can remove margin left from col-md-6 paragraph

Tags: css

I have been trying to remove margin-left from col-md-6 from p tag for media query but it was not working

I have tried this

```css
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:425px) {
  .col-md-6 {
    /* No Space */
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try         margin-left: 0 !important;

Answer (score 0):

It is not taking margin. Col-md-6 always takes padding-left and padding-right of 15px.

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 425px){
.col-md-6{ padding-left: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap col use `padding` just add class `pl-0` for `col-md-6` and if you want it on specific screen width just use bootstrap breakpoints like : `pl-md-0`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-6 bg-danger">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 bg-primary">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be removed with `.no-gutters`. This removes the negative margins from .row and the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns.

Then you can give your desired margin or padding to the divs. Hope it'll solve your problem

Answer (score -3):

You need to switch your values:

```css
@media (max-width:425px ) and (min-width:320px) { 
.col-md-6{ margin-left:0;} 
}
```

thats all...